# How to send MP3 file from power automate to whisper-1 API

Tags: power-automate

I am currently trying to send an audio file (mp3) to the openAI endpoint for speech to text, using power automate for such task.

The issue I have is that I am sending both "Get file content" return and its conversion to base64 as an attempt to send the file. Nevertheless I keep on getting the error `Could not parse multipart form`.

I used postman to test wether if my headers and file were fine and it works normally, so I know its a matter of how I am sending the file.
[image: var declaration]
[image: http request]